# iPhone audio super quiet

Tags: iphone, operating-system, audio

For some reason - my app's audio is super quiet on an iPhone. All good on the iPad and Simulator and iPod Touch and even on another iPhone, but barely audible on one of the iPhones. The iPhone that plays that audio at the right level is running OS 4.3.2 (8H7). The iPhone that plays the audio extremely quietly is running OS 4.2.1 (8C148a) Any ideas?

Here's the code, though it's a device issue:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sound ofType:@"caf"];
sounds = [[SoundEffect alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
[sounds play];
```

In SoundEffect.h/.m is Copyright (C) 2010 Apple Inc. and I use it for audio playback in all my apps.

THANKS!

Comment: From what you are saying you are probably having a problem with your iphone playing sounds. To check if that's the case play something from itunes "ipod" on iphone.

Comment: Thanks - I should have mentioned that I did check it by playing music and videos on the phone and the audio worked well on those.

Comment: Check this question, this person had the same issue with version 4.2.1 http://stackoverflow.com/q/985135/277021

Answer (score 0):

Searching the net is showing that there is a bug in 4.2.1 on some devices, either plain sound very quite or not at all. Just upgrade to newer version or restore your iphone.

Comment: Wow - updated the OS to 4.3.3 (8J2) and the audio is still playing very very quiet. So weird, like I said the audio works just fine in the simulator, on the iPad, on an iPod Touch, and even on another iPhone, but not on this iPhone. All the other audio on this iPhone works fine, just not the audio in this app I'm working on. WEIRD!